# Strange behavior with a conditional mutate with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My apologies if this topic has been discussed somewhere, I was not able to find it out.

I was trying to apply a quite simple conditional `mutate()` with `dplyr` when I noticed something quite weird to me, I explain:

Let's say that in a data.frame I want to modify a variable (here `VALUE`) according to the value of a specific row in each group (here `COND`). 
The modification is: "*if the last value of `COND` within the current group is 0, then set `VALUE` to 99 for the current group, otherwhise do nothing*"

Here's what I naturally wrote:

```
tab <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
  COND = c(c(1,0,0), rep(1,3)),
  VALUE = 1:6
)
tab %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = ifelse(COND[n()] == 0,
                        99, 
                        VALUE))

#      ID   COND  VALUE
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1    99
# 2     1     0    99
# 3     1     0    99
# 4     2     1     4
# 5     2     1     4 <
# 6     2     1     4 <
```

The propagation went well for the first group since `VALUE` is now 99 which is legitimate (`COND` == 0 in row 3) whereas I was surprised to see that `VALUE` also changed for the other group by propagating the first value of `VALUE` within the group while the condition is **not** fulfilled.

Can someone enlight me on what I am misunderstanding here?

Expected result was:

```
#      ID   COND  VALUE
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1    99
# 2     1     0    99
# 3     1     0    99
# 4     2     1     4
# 5     2     1     5 <
# 6     2     1     6 <
```

[edit] I also tried using `case_when()` which apparently I do not manage well either:

```
tab %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = case_when(
    COND[n()] == 0 ~ 99,
    TRUE ~ VALUE
  ))
# Erreur : must be a double vector, not an integer vector
```

One workaround that would be to calculate an intermediate variable, but I am quite surprised having to do that.

Possible solution:

```
tab %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(TEST_COND = COND[n()] == 0,
         VALUE = ifelse(TEST_COND, 99, VALUE))

#       ID  COND VALUE TEST_COND
#     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
# 1     1     1    99 TRUE     
# 2     1     0    99 TRUE     
# 3     1     0    99 TRUE     
# 4     2     1     4 FALSE    
# 5     2     1     5 FALSE    
# 6     2     1     6 FALSE

# Yeepee
```

Comment: Is your dataframe correct? in the table COND[1] is 1 but in the dataframe it is 0. This may affect the answer! Should `COND = c(1, rep(0,2), rep(1,3))`?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo, I fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to add an intermediate variable; see revised answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```r
library(dplyr)

tab <- data.frame(
  ID = c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
  COND = c(1, rep(0,2), rep(1,3)),
  VALUE = 1:6
)


tab %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(VALUE = case_when(last(COND) == 0 ~ 99L,
                           TRUE ~ VALUE))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID  COND VALUE
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#> 1     1     1    99
#> 2     1     0    99
#> 3     1     0    99
#> 4     2     1     4
#> 5     2     1     5
#> 6     2     1     6
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Updated my answer which is giving the required result;  hopefully this is acceptable!

Comment: The issue is that generating `VALUE` in your original data frame results in an integer vector check `typeof(1:6)`. The output of case_when the condition is met needs to be an integer - which the answer is now or if  you use `99` this is treated as a double you therefore need to adjust `VALUE` to be of type  double hence `as.numeric(VALUE)` is the alternative way to achieve the same result. Hope this helps.